# Sidenav with affix - links do not wrap to next line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, sidenav

If I have the following, the link text wraps to the next line beautifuly:

```
<div class="sidenav" id="site-navbar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
      <li><a href="#h0">A very very very very very very very very very long thing</a></li>
```

However, if I add affix, the text stays on the same line and overlaps onto the main content column:

```
<div class="sidenav" id="site-navbar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix">
      <li><a href="#h0">A very very very very very very very very very long thing</a></li>
```

Is there a way to fix this with css?  Also, can I do it without editing the current CSS.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the overflow:
https://jsfiddle.net/75nLbwyb/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Example of navbar overflow</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="sidenav" id="navbar-example" data-spy="affix">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-offset-top="1">
            <li><a href="#headline0">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#headline1">Section 2 - a very very long thing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#headline2">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="headline0">
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
        </div>
        <p>
          blah </p>
        <div id="headline1">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
        </div>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        <div id="headline2">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          fddf
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's not from my side. But one question. The issue appear only at scroll start right?

Comment: @ErrorinException Take a look at the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/75nLbwyb/ it should be present without scroll now

Comment: in the fiddle, even if I removed the data-spy, it's still not breaking

Comment: ```.affix``` is made fixed on scroll, causing its width to be defined by inner content, and not by outer ```.col-sm-3``` container column (which has a ```width: 25%``` set on it). To fix this you need to specify ```max-width``` for ```.nav.affix```, like nstungcom mentioned. But the additional problem is that ```.col-sm-3``` is fluid, and layout is responsive. So you can not just set a fixed ```max-width``` in CSS, you will need to use JS to update ```max-width``` according to the current ```.col-sm-3``` width.

Comment: And you will need to adapt the whole thing accordingly when responsive layout is changed (i.e. on narrow screens)

Answer (score 5):

Main problem you face is that your `.nav` container (which own the `.affix` class) gets `position:fixed` as soon you scroll. Fixed elements orientate themselves to the browser viewport, this is the reason why its ignoring the width of the parent `.col-sm-3` container from bootstrap (the 25% of the container width) and overlapping the text to the right.

Your only solution is to add a width value to the `.affix` class therefor your nav container wont break layout. HTML markup is fine so far! Maybe you need to make some adjustments for mobile styling (keep that in mind):

```
.nav.affix {  
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff; 
  z-index: 1;
  /* background and zindex for mobile styles, currently layout breaks  */
}
```

> Check the sidebar of the bootstrap documentation. They adding a width to the affix class element too! — https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#code

Comment: Interesting - it would seem like calculating this dynamically would be better - but this definitely works –

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy this is what I was explaining. Fixed positioned elements can only be dynamic to the browser viewport width, not to elements on the website!

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy : I think there is no better way to fix this. Fixed elements are quite uncontrollable :)

Answer (score 1):

Try use flexbox

```css
.container-new {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <title>Example of navbar overflow</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container container-new">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="sidenav" id="navbar-example">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix"  data-offset-top="1">
              <li><a href="#headline0">Section 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#headline1">Section 2 - a very very long thing asd as das das das das d</a></li>
              <li><a href="#headline2">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="headline0">
            <h1>Section 1</h1></div>
          <p>
            blah </p>
          <div id="headline1">
            <h2>Section 2</h2></div>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          <div id="headline2">
            <h2>Section 3</h2>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
            <p> blah blah blah blah </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            fddf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75nLbwyb/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
 css:

  body {
  position: relative;
  }
  .affix {
  top: 20px;
   }
  div.col-sm-9 div {
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 28px;
   }

 @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
 #section1, #section2, #section3, #section41, #section42  {
    margin-left: 150px;
    }
  }


 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3" >
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="section1">    
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2"> 
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>        
  <div id="section3">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41">
    <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>      
  <div id="section42">
    <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

A fixed element can still inherit its width from its parent, `width: inherit` seems to do the trick, no need to dynamically calculate it:

```
.sidenav.affix {
  width: inherit;
}

.sidenav.affix .nav-pills {
  width: calc(80% - 30px);
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiabani/nfatr51y/).

I had to move `data-spy="affix"` from `ul` to `.sidenav`. Sorry for not being able to test it cross browser from where I am. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It can not properly inherit widths in percentages.

Comment: What do you mean by _properly_?

Comment: This: http://i.imgur.com/HBFcPYP.png (parent ```.col-sm-3``` has different width which should be inherited, but it is not).

Comment: Well this is what meant by _adjust this to your needs_. It definitely needs some tuning, but the idea of inheriting width from `.col-sm-3` is much cleaner and dynamic

Comment: If you adjust it to a new value every 50-100px of screen width with media queries then probably it will be tolerable to some degree, depending on requirements. In some cases you may need to adjust it with 1-2 pixel increments. This is manual width recalculation, in worst scenario — for every pixel of screen width. How is that clean? And you do not know yet how other browsers treat it, you may end up using browser sniffing/hacks to manually recalculate it cross-browser. It is not viable and bulletproof solution, but a momentary cosmetic hack.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. I have updated my answer, where as you see not a single media query is necessary. Let me know what you think.

Comment: If a proper width is not inherited, then css can't do much about it. Only if you write a ton of css for all screen widths with 1-pixel increments it may be sufficient, but I would not even try. For a smooth transition to fixed state on scroll, you need to have the exact same widths for ```.sidenav``` contents between normal state and ```position: fixed``` state, for every possible screen width, think about it

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and got it fixed by setting a max-width to the affix element.

In your case:

```
.nav.affix {
  max-width: 145px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75nLbwyb/2/

Comment: Interesting - it would seem like calculating this dynamically would be better - but this definitely works